# Crash when pushing to another controller after `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to have the app go to a different view controller after the user chooses a photo from the picker.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        let previewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "previewVC") as! PreviewViewController
        previewController.previewImage.image = image
        previewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(previewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

`previewController` simply has an image view (`@IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!`) and a button to post the photo, so I'm trying to set that image view to display the picked image.

However, I get a crash "unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value" on the `previewController.previewImage.image = image` line. `previewImage` in the previewController is nil in the debugger, but I'm not sure why - isn't that being set as soon as the user hits "choose" in the picker?

Is there another step involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary cause of your issue is that you are trying to access the outlets of the view controller too soon. The view controller's views and outlets are not created and assigned immediately after instantiating the view controller.

It's also poor design to attempt to directly access the views of a view controller from code outside of that view controller. The proper solution, in this case, is to add a `UIImage` property that you can set. Then let the view controller update its own image view based on the value of that image property at the proper time (such as in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: I added `var img: UIImage?` to preview controller and set `previewController.img = image` in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. Then in preview controller's viewDidLoad I set `self.previewImage.image = img`. And while there's no crash now, nothing happens when I tap on choose in the picker.

Comment: Define "nothing happens". Is the preview controller pushed? Is the current view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: No, literally nothing happens - there's no crash, but neither "choose" nor "cancel" on the picker are tappable.

Comment: And both view controllers are in a navigation controller.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I needed to call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` after `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(previewController, animated: true)`. Seems to be working for now but as you said it doesn't feel like the best/most efficient way of going about this.

Comment: So basically you had two big issues. The one asked about in this question which I answered, and then a new issue that appeared once the first one was fixed.

Comment: @rmaddy you're right, I selected your answer. I made a different question to address the problem I'm having now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your function

```
dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
```

In the completion, you can define a closure that does whatever you want.

Comment: for whomever down voted me, can you please comment so i can get what's wrong.

Comment: I didn't down vote but your answer doesn't address the issue posted in the question. Your answer is code that does need to be added but it doesn't solve the immediate issue of the crash.

Comment: I downvoted you. Like @rmaddy said, your answer doesn't address the crash issue at all.